# Stationary distribution of multidimensional birth-death process

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, numerical-methods

I am considering a 2D birth-death process with a rate matrix $A$, with

(1) state space: each dimension can take an integer value from $1$ to $V$ and there are two dimensions. Therefore the size of the state space is $V^2$. Denote $(i,j)$ to be a state where the first dimension takes $i$ and the second takes $j$.

(2) The two dimensions are equivalent. i.e. the rate from $(i,j)$ to $(i+1,j)$ equals to the rate from $(j,i)$ to $(j,i+1)$; and the rate from $(i,j)$ to $(i-1,j)$ equals to the rate from $(j,i)$ to $(j,i-1)$.

(3) The forward and the backward rates are not equal. i.e. the rate from $(i,j)$ to $(i+1,j)$  is not same as the one from $(i,j)$ to $(i-1,j)$. Therefore $A$ is not symmetric.

If we enumerate all the states in the order $(1,1),(1,2),\dots,(1,V),(2,1),(2,2),\dots,(V,V)$, we can decomposite $A$ to

$A=P+T P T$ where $P$ is a block diagonal matrix with $V$ block rate matrices of size $V$ and $T$ is a permutation matrix. My question is whether there exists a convenient way to calculate the stationary distribution of $A$ (i.e. $\pi' A=0$) by handling $P$ and $T$. The issue is the matrix $A$ can be very large, so a direct QR or SVD or state-space reduction for the matrix $A$ is not really possible.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)